# sample space in Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples (5th ed)*.
He state Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law as followings

> If $X_1, X_2,...$ are independent and identically distributed(i.i.d) and $ A \in \varepsilon $ then $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$

where $ \varepsilon $ is exchangeable $\sigma$-field.

In proof, He claimed that

> Let $A_n \in \sigma(X_1, ... X_n)$ so that $P(A_n \Delta A) \rightarrow 0$
> Then $A_n$ can be written as $\{\omega : (\omega_1, ... , \omega_n) \in B_n\}$ where $B_n \in S^{n} $

I understand that such $A_n$ exists in meausure theoretical sense.
But I can't understand what "$A_n$ can be written as~" means.

I think $\omega = (\omega_1 , \omega_2 , ...) $ if $X_i(\omega) = \omega_i$ for given random variables. But, Is it well-defined?
Since random variable may not be injective, this expression using coordinates is not well-defined I think. (different element of sample space can be expressed as same coordinates)
How can I understand this expression?

Thanks.

Comment: [Section 2.1.4 of the book](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf#page=61) describes how Durrett is setting up independent random variables, which is the $X_i((\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n))=\omega_i$ map you see here. I'm not sure why you think it is not well-defined, and why you are concerned about injectivity.

Comment: @angryavian I confused what comes first in definition. I think that first sample space is given, then secondly random variable is defined on sample space, and finally distribution function is determined. 
 So if $X_i (\omega) = \omega_i $ and $X_i(\tau) = \omega_i$ (non injective random variable), then $\omega = (\omega_i) = \tau$ so I concerned about well-definedness.
 But in the view point of book, it seems that first distribution was given, then we can find sample space and random variables. It's strange for me because we have to modify sample space depends on number of random variables)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X : (\Omega, \mu) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable. You can then define a new random variable $X' : (\mathbb{R}, \mu') \to \mathbb{R}$ by $X'(\omega)=\omega$ where the measure on the domain is $$\mu'(E)=P(X \in E) = \mu(X^{-1}(E))$$ for any measurable $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. So in some sense you are throwing away the old probability space $(\Omega, \mu)$. [$\mu'$ is called the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure).]

So if you have $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ all represented as maps $(\mathbb{R}, \mu_n) \to \mathbb{R}$ you can take the product of the measures $\nu = \mu_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \mu_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and reformulate each $X_i$ as a map $(\mathbb{R}^n, \nu) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X_i((\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)) = \omega_i$.

Comment: Thanks! But I still wonder 'why we can consider pushforward measure and product measure?' It seems we can 'identify' random variable with pushforward random variable, so we can move story on sample space to $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, you mean wlog we may assume sample space is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, right?
 But it's strange for me since we cannot identify sample space to real line, since there may not be bijection from sample space to real line. moreover what occurs to sample space if we add one new variable? So I still cannot understand why we can wlog assume sample space is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.